# Why does my SimpleDateFormat parsing not work?

Tags: java, android, date, parsing

I need help parsing the `String` date

```
"Thu Oct 22 13:51:51 CEST 2015"
```

with `SimpleDateFormat`, but I'm not able to find the correct pattern.

Here is what I've tried

```
String date = "Thu Oct 22 13:51:51 CEST 2015";

try {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E M d H:m:s z y");
    d1 = dateFormat.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    Log.e(null, String.valueOf(e1));
}
```

I get back the error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 22 13:51:51 CEST 2015" (at offset 0)
```

---

**UPDATE**

I tried the solution below by durron597 adapting it to my needs:

```
String date = "Thu Oct 22 13:51:51 CEST 2015";
try {
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.US);
     Date d1 = dateFormat.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
     Log.e("null", String.valueOf(e1));
}
```

but in the logcat I keep getting the error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 22 13:51:51 CEST 2015" (at offset 20)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Use more letters for the longer versions of the Date elements.

In particular the problem in your case was probably the Month portion, which you can see from this part of the [Javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

You only had one character for Month, it tried to interpet it as a number, found a letter, and failed.

#### You also need to specify the US locale, as these are United States dates.

Specify the [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to use in translating the name of the day of the week, “Thu”. You are in Italy (it says so in your profile); when I use [`Locale.Italy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ITALY) on my machine, I get the same error as you do. If you specify [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US) as in the below code, it should work.

#### Update: Android doesn't support [three letter time zones, according to this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)):

> Other than the special cases "UTC" and "GMT" (which are synonymous in this context, both corresponding to UTC), Android does not support the deprecated three-letter time zone IDs used in Java 1.1.

You should be able to replace your Europe time zone with the full name of the time zone defined in the [official “tz” time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (formerly known as [Olson database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)). For example, [`Europe/Rome`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Rome) instead of "CEST".

Try this instead:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.US);
date.replace("CEST", "Europe/Rome");
Date d1 = dateFormat.parse(date);
```

Here's a full working example:

```
public class DateExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "Thu Oct 22 13:51:51 CEST 2015";

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.US);
        date.replace("CEST", "Europe/Rome");
        Date d1 = dateFormat.parse(date);
        System.out.println(d1);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Thu Oct 22 06:51:51 CDT 2015
```

Comment: @GiovanniDiGregorio Ugh this sort of thing is why I hate `SimpleDateFormat` and always use [Joda Time `DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) in my code.

Comment: I'm finishing my time. Although step absolutely to JodaTime, I continue to update this question because I'm curious to know the solution.Thanks for your time, you deserve a vote.

Comment: @GiovanniDiGregorio Heh, thanks, I hope to get a checkmark too. I've updated it one last time, going to give up if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: He doesn't fix ;) see you tomorrow to defeat the beast…